# Upgrade jboss fuse oracle driver to 19c compatible driver

Tags: jbossfuse, ojdbc

I am using jboss fuse with oracle 11g. We are planning to upgrade the database to oracle 19c and the 11g jdbc driver is not compatible with 19c database. I copied 19c drive to lib directory but did not work. Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using the 19c JDBC drivers from [Central Maven](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) or from [OTN](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html). Can you specify the error that you are getting?